# How to create a LUKS encrypted file in a vboxsf mountpoint?

Tags: virtualbox, luks

I am trying to create a LUKS encrypted file in a VirtualBox image. It works fine unless the encrypted file resides in a VirtualBox shared folder.

The error output is:

```
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.945147 s, 11.1 MB/s

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on test.tomb irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase: 
Verify passphrase: 
Enter passphrase for test.tomb: 
mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Creating filesystem with 8192 1k blocks and 2048 inodes

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (1024 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

mount: /dev/mapper/tomb is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/tomb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

---

It is easily reproducible in Vagrant.

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"

  config.vm.synced_folder 'tombs', '/tombs'

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y cryptsetup
    mkdir -p /media/tomb
    cat > /test.sh <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash

cd \$1
dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.tomb bs=1M count=10

cryptsetup -y luksFormat test.tomb
cryptsetup luksOpen test.tomb tomb
mkfs.ext4 -j /dev/mapper/tomb

mount /dev/mapper/tomb /media/tomb
ls /media/tomb

umount /media/tomb
cryptsetup luksClose tomb
EOF

  SHELL
end
```

Setup Vagrant:

```
mkdir tombs
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Test it:

```
sudo su -
bash /test.sh /root  # works fine
bash /test.sh /tombs # does not work
```

`mount | grep tombs` shows:

```
tombs on /tombs type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime)
```

`dmesg` shows:

```
[  267.574832] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

**Is this a known restriction when the LUKS file is in a shared folder? If not, what could I be doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce using the steps you describe.
Shared folders are a special functionality of the guest additions kernel modules, and may not be functionally equivalent to a local drive.

I also tried to create a LUKS file-drive inside of a loopback device (as that is how I have done LUKS file-drives in the past) and it can't even format the file, it fails on the post check.

I also tried forcing the owner of the share in Vagrantfile to be root, did not appear to make a difference. Also tried adding `root` and `vagrant` to the `vboxsf` group, that did not help either.

So the short answer is yes it appears to be a limitation of "simple" native virtualbox shared folders.
One thing I did not try was that vagrant supports nfs-style shared folders, that would take a bit more effort but may behave differently.